# How to install gcc and g++ compilers

Tags: installation, compiling, gcc

I have tried these commands in terminal ,

```
sudu apt-get upgrade
sudu apt-get update
sudu apt-get install build essential
```

but failed. Please help me, I am getting the following error.

```
No command 'sudu' found, did you mean:
Command 'sudo' from package 'sudo' (main)
Command 'sudo' from package 'sudo-ldap' (universe)
Command 'tudu' from package 'tudu' (universe)
sudu: command not found
```

Answer (score 7):

#### It's `sudo`, not `sudu`

Also, run `update` before `upgrade`. And it's better to run `dist-upgrade` as that upgrades more thoroughly.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Note that the error output you posted included the answer already!

> No command 'sudu' found, did you mean: Command 'sudo' from package 'sudo' (main)

Alternatively, just use the graphical application "Ubuntu Software Center" to install the package. Click this link: [build-essential [image: Install build-essential]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/build-essential) or search it manually in the software center.

Comment: He did not ask for distro upgrade

Comment: @Ashok it isn't. `dist-upgrade` does not upgrade to a newer Ubuntu release.

Comment: `dist-upgrade` installs new software as well, like new kernel versions are seen as new software and not an upgrade of the current one. New versions of programs that's only downloaded as a whole package and not an upgrade will only be downloaded with `dist-upgrade`.

Answer (score 0):

Write g++ in the search box of Ubuntu software centre. You can find GNU C++ compiler, install it. You can install "Geany" or "Eclipse" to write C++ program, for beginners Geany is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Ya, easiest way for new users to remember is, super user (**su**) and **d'oh**, which you say to yourself after trying the command as a regular user and getting the error.

*'Dammit, have to be super user, d'oh!'*   **sudo**.

Comment: "super user do" (as in, "*do* this") might be an easier mnemonic (for users of any skill level). I do like that yours is phonetic, though. :)